# Preseed directive to skip another CD/DVD scanning

Tags: debian, debian-installer, preseed

Please see the image below, is there a `preseed` directive to skip this `Debian9` installer step?

Currently I use the following config relevant to the package manager:

```
### Apt setup
d-i apt-setup/non-free boolean true
d-i apt-setup/contrib boolean true
d-i apt-setup/local0/source boolean true

### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard

### Mirror settings
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string httpredir.debian.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
```

[image: Debian9 Installer]

Comment: From the top of my head, you have to add a debian repository for it to be used.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Please see edited question, I indeed use a mirror.

Comment: would you please add to question how are you making the security update?

Comment: `security.debian.org` is added to the `sources.list` regardless the mirror I choose. Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For it not to scan your DVD/netinst image, add these directives to your preseeding configuration:

```
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-first boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-next boolean false   
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-failed boolean false
```

Comment: Do you have URL to the docs? I couldn't find these directives in the [Stretch example preseed](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/example-preseed.txt) file.

Comment: You find them in linaro cfg files https://images.validation.linaro.org/kvm/debian-8.3.0-cd1-preseed.cfg and I suspect they were patches done around 2014 after a bug was filled

Comment: The documentation for this preseed thing is horrible and scattered all over the internet.

Comment: Glad I found this answer, happen on Debian 10 and I don't think it's patched.